# chord recogination by multiple fundamental frequency estimation

Tags: audio, pitch

I'm gonna implement multiple frequency estimation by summing harmonics amplitude!
I've read Anssi Klapuri paper but i can't understand him.
first of all he said spectral whitening i did it by i don't know whether it's true! after that i have to implement this formula:
$$s(\tau)=\sum_{m=0}^Mg(\tau,m)max_{}|Y(k)|$$‎
i can't understand what this $\tau$ is!
please give some hint to implement it or some other method for implementation.

Comment: Can you link to the paper you're reading? It's very difficult to interpret that formula on its own.

Comment: yes, [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CD0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpdf.aminer.org%2F000%2F439%2F638%2Fmultiple_fundamental_frequency_estimation_by_summing_harmonic_amplitudes.pdf&ei=-hz2UaP2DsSX1AXN1YGYAw&usg=AFQjCNGksv-OaWkeRnd_EWNA8dsFe7Z_Jg&sig2=9DnoJzbTSWWfKJIlSKL5EQ&bvm=bv.49784469,d.d2k), thank you for your answering.

Answer (score 3):

$g(\tau,m)$ is the weighting function used in the paper. Equation (7) tells you how to calculate its value.

$\tau$ is the fundamental period which is the reciprocal of the fundamental frequency, $f_0$. If the fundamental frequency is 440 Hz then $\tau$ is $1/440 = 2.27$ ms.

Comment: thanks.
for implementing it on MATLAB is it correct that i use $f{0}/f{s}$ and $\tau*f{s}$?